# Is it good or bad practice to flag records in database instead of deleting them?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a webshop application, and right now I am debating over deleting data from the database when prompted by the admin, or only flaggind the data to be deleted as deleted. Right now, the balance tips over flagging because of the following advantages:

Consider the two tables `Product` and `Order`. These two tables are in a relation with each other, an `Order` table may have attached several rows from the `Product` table. If I plain and simply delete something from the `Product` table, later on, some rows in the `Order` table will contain invalid data, because the deleted `Product` rows are unreachable. If I only flag the `Product` row as deleted, I can still show a history of the products ordered, that are already deleted. This is one advantage over flagging, but I also know about a disadvantage: the tables can get very large very quick, because of no data deletion.

What other advantages/disadvantages does flaging have over deleting? What is considered good practice, flaging, deleting, or depends on the environment? If it depends on the environment, what would be considered good practice in my webshop environment?

Thank you!

Comment: It's fairly obvious that it always depends on the use case. Even in the context of a shop, you cannot delete a user if you need its data for tax stuff, but you need to delete it to comply with data protection laws.

Comment: It depends, if you are showing data in reports or dependent on other reports like in your case then I will suggest to not delete just update status. If not necessary and no use in another reports then delete is a good option because no need to keep unnecessary data in database.

Comment: In my territory there are data retention rules which drive company based archiving and deletion policies. It's best that the business decides what they are and that IT understands fully how the data is linked and what must be done to cleanly delete.

Comment: In the case of products, look at web sites like Amazon.  The will still display products that you can no longer get - in these cases it may link to other alternative products.